# SoftLayer API returns text instead of json?

Tags: node.js, json, api, axios

I've been using an api with curl as follows:
`curl -X GET -g -u $SL_USER:$SL_APIKEY "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware` and I used to get json response:

```
{"accountId":1414807,"bareMetalInstanceFlag":0,"domain":"regtech.cloud.com","fullyQualifiedDomainName":"dal1302vsrx001.regtech.cloud.com","hardwareStatusId":5,"hostname":"dal1302vsrx001","id":1579801,"manufacturerSerialNumber":"C819UAH12CC0374","notes":"","provisionDate":"2020-02-19T17:16:02-06:00","serialNumber":"SL01HOPT","serviceProviderId":1,"serviceProviderResourceId":null,"globalIdentifier":"957011c1-126f-4cc9-9c95-b7470f05d238","hardwareFunction":{"code":"WEBSVR","description":"Web Server","id":3},"hardwareStatus":{"id":5,"status":"ACTIVE"},"networkManagementIpAddress":"10.220.221.231","primaryBackendIpAddress":"10.220.221.222","primaryIpAddress":"55.517.245.230","privateIpAddress":"10.220.221.222"}
```

Now, I'm trying to reimplement this in axios js and I get text by default. I tried to explicitly set response-type to json but not working! Please help if you see something wrong I made in the code below:

```
api_endpoint="https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware"
axios.get(api_endpoint, {
    params:{
        resultLimit: 1
    },
    auth: {
        username: SL_USER,
        password: SL_APIKEY
    },
    responseType: 'application/json',
    timeout: 20000
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
})
.catch(function (ex) {
    console.log("There was an error obtaining the product id")
    console.log(ex)
})
```

Here's the format I get from axios code:

```
META_PROPERTIES='ACCOUNT_ID BARE_METAL_INSTANCE_FLAG DOMAIN FULLY_QUALIFIED_DOMAIN_NAME HARDWARE_STATUS_ID HOSTNAME ID MANUFACTURER_SERIAL_NUMBER NOTES PROVISION_DATE SERIAL_NUMBER SERVICE_PROVIDER_ID SERVICE_PROVIDER_RESOURCE_ID GLOBAL_IDENTIFIER HARDWARE_FUNCTION HARDWARE_STATUS NETWORK_MANAGEMENT_IP_ADDRESS PRIMARY_BACKEND_IP_ADDRESS PRIMARY_IP_ADDRESS PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS'
META_PROPERTY_TYPES='SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR OBJECT OBJECT SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR SCALAR'

ACCOUNT_ID='1414807'
BARE_METAL_INSTANCE_FLAG='0'
DOMAIN='regtech.cloud.com'
FULLY_QUALIFIED_DOMAIN_NAME='dal1302vsrx001.regtech.cloud.com'
.
.
.
```

Comment: Per the axios doc, change to `responseType: 'json'`.

Comment: Tried that initially with no luck -_-. thanks tho

Comment: You need to go to the doc for the site and see what exactly you need to pass it so it will send you back JSON.  And, you could also compare the EXACT requests sent from both your curl and from your Javascript and see what is different between the two requests.

Comment: Thanks, I went back and looked and it turns out, it requires you to specify the type in the URL. thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added .json to the end of my url.

[image]